# A Jasmine spec timed out when resetting the WebDriver Control Flow

Tags: protractor

When I am Running this Spec I am getting this issue.
What can I do to fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In the .config file, you will have a variable called defaultTimeoutInterval set it to a large value like shown below:

```
 jasmineNodeOpts: {
        showColors: true,
        defaultTimeoutInterval: 300000,
        print: function() {}
    }
```